# How do I fix "ImportError: cannot import name urandom" when running fabric in virtualenv?

Tags: 12.04

End of stack trace:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, in <module>
    from os import urandom as _urandom
ImportError: cannot import name urandom

There was a problem importing our SSH library (see traceback above).
```

Not an issue in 11.10. Problem started after I upgraded to 12.04. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by following the suggestion in [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/954595/comments/7) on [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/954595) and re-running virtualenv on my virtualenv directory:

```
virtualenv /path/to/your/virtualenv
```